# problema con array de números aleatorios no repetidos

Tags: vb.net

básicamente lo que quiero hacer es hacer un array de 27 números aleatorios no repetidos, dependiendo de en que columna este el array el número aleatorio tendrá un rango diferente.

esta función genera un número aleatorio dependiendo de la columna del array

```
Private Function GeneraNumero(ByVal columna)
        Dim value As Integer
        If columna = 0 Then
            value = CInt((1 - 9) * Rnd() + 9)

        ElseIf columna = 1 Then
            value = CInt((10 - 19) * Rnd() + 19)
        ElseIf columna = 2 Then
            value = CInt((20 - 29) * Rnd() + 29)
        ElseIf columna = 3 Then
            value = CInt((30 - 39) * Rnd() + 39)
        ElseIf columna = 4 Then
            value = CInt((40 - 49) * Rnd() + 49)
        ElseIf columna = 5 Then
            value = CInt((50 - 59) * Rnd() + 59)
        ElseIf columna = 6 Then
            value = CInt((60 - 69) * Rnd() + 69)
        ElseIf columna = 7 Then
            value = CInt((70 - 79) * Rnd() + 79)
        ElseIf columna = 8 Then
            value = CInt((80 - 90) * Rnd() + 90)
        End If
        Return value

    End Function
```

y esta subrutina es para generar un "carton" con 27 botones y con números no repetidos

```
 Private Sub GenerarCarton()
        Dim repetido As Boolean = False
        filas = 3
        columnas = 9
        Dim contador As Integer = 0
        Dim numeros(27) As Integer
        Dim aleatorio As Integer

        For i = 0 To filas - 1
            For j = 0 To columnas - 1
                contador += 1
                Do
                    For k = 0 To numeros.Length - 1
                        aleatorio = GeneraNumero(j)
                        If numeros(k) <> aleatorio Then
                            numeros(k) = aleatorio
                            repetido = True
                        Else

                            repetido = False
                        End If
                    Next
                Loop While repetido = True

                Dim miboton As New Button

                With miboton
                    .Name = "boton" & i & j
                    .Width = 50
                    .Height = 50
                    .Text = numeros(contador)
                    .Top = .Height * ((i - 1) Mod filas) + 100
                    .Left = .Width * (j) + 10
                End With
                TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(miboton)
                AddHandler miboton.MouseDown, AddressOf miclick
            Next j

        Next i

    End Sub
```

De momento genera los botones y los rellena con los números en los rangos correctos pero siguen saliendo números repetidos y no se por donde tirar, si alguien me puede echar una manita le estoy muy agradecido.

Comment: Al ser rangos tan pequeños, es normal que los numeros se repitan.Lo que debes hacer es almacenar en algun sitio los numeros que han salido y comprobar cuando generes uno si ya ha salido anteriormente. En ese caso, vuelves a generar otro hasta dar con uno que no esté en la lista.

Comment: eso es lo que trato de hacer, hago un bucle do while y cuando genero el numero recorro el array de numeros generados si no es igual entonces lo mete y sale del bucle para iterar otra vez si es igual vuelve al bucle donde genera otro numero aleatorio, no se que falla

Answer (score 0):

Intenta Avanzar la Opción Después del Do Para Que Genere un Nuevo Numero antes del ciclo For que Genera para Generar un nuevo número aleatorio

```
Private Sub GenerarCarton()
    Dim repetido As Boolean = False
    filas = 3
    columnas = 9
    Dim contador As Integer = 0
    Dim numeros(27) As Integer
    Dim aleatorio As Integer

    For i = 0 To filas - 1
        For j = 0 To columnas - 1
            contador += 1
            Do
                aleatorio = GeneraNumero(j) 
                For k = 0 To numeros.Length - 1
                    If numeros(k) <> aleatorio Then
                        repetido = True
                        Exit For  
                    Else
                        numeros(k) = aleatorio   
                        repetido = False  
                    End If  
                Next
            Loop While repetido = True

            Dim miboton As New Button

            With miboton
                .Name = "boton" & i & j
                .Width = 50
                .Height = 50
                .Text = numeros(contador)
                .Top = .Height * ((i - 1) Mod filas) + 100
                .Left = .Width * (j) + 10
            End With
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(miboton)
            AddHandler miboton.MouseDown, AddressOf miclick
        Next j

    Next i

End Sub
```